# Is a BJT at the edge of saturation when Vce is at a given constant or when Vce=Vbe?

Tags: transistors, bjt

We are shamelessly inconsistent with this in our Electronics intro class. If Vce,sat is given we use that but if it isn't we make sure that the base-collector junction is neither forward nor reverse biased and find it ourselves. The TA horribly failed at explaining this so I thought I would ask for the infinite wisdom of random strangers online.

I understand how the junction biasing would be decisive of this but the Vce=0.2V approximations independent of base voltage also exist so I want to learn where that comes from and which is the more correct way.

Comment: I've never really done any BJT circuit design, but VCE=0.2V seems low to me. Isn't it used for MOSFETs? I learned that an NPN BJT is in saturation if VCB>0.

Comment: This sounds like one for @BrianDrummond

Comment: for saturation region, you just need to check BE and BC and they both need to be forward

Answer (score 2):

Saturation occurs when increasing base current does not reduce collector voltage.
as such it s depedant to some extent on what the load is,

Depending on the degree of precision needed and what you're trying to do 
you can use different approximations for saturation voltage.

For some applications you want to cause saturation to minimize heating, in others you want to avoid it to maximize speed.

Comment: *it is dependant to some extent on what the load is* - in the limit, as the external circuit's C-E impedance goes to zero, the saturation won't occur before the part self-destructs, or you could alternatively look at it as if the circuit was saturated at any base current, since the C-E voltage is approximately constant, and nothing you do on the base will reduce it :) It is demonstrates the paradoxical nature of this particular definition of saturation :) (there's nothing really wrong with it, I just thought to provide some food for thought)

Answer (score 1):

\$V_{CE(SAT)}\$ varies by part and is a function of the amount of collector-emitter current that's flowing through the part. So don't assume that \$V_{CE(SAT)}=0.2\,\text{V}\$ is a typical value; in the "real world" it's not.

That being said, when using simple models to solve transistor circuit problems, rough estimates like \$V_{CE(SAT)}\le0.2\,\text{V}\$ or \$V_{CB}<0\$ or \$\beta_{sat}\le40\$ are commonly used as the hallmarks of saturation for an NPN BJT. These estimates are based upon more sophisticated math models, or from SPICE simulations, or testing actual parts with a device analyzer (a.k.a., a curve tracer), etc. *(NB: The estimates shown here are not universal; they vary from one textbook to the next.)*

> We are shamelessly inconsistent with this in our Electronics intro class.

When using simple mathematical models to solve transistor circuits, one usually starts by making an assumption—e.g., the transistor is operating in forward-active mode—and then solving the circuit under the assumed conditions and checking whether the solution values confirm or reject the assumption. In other words, when using simple math models the solution process is hit-or-miss. If it's a miss, the solution values usually hint at the actual mode of operation—e.g., one assumes forward-active mode, but the solution values indicate the transistor cannot be in forward-active mode and is probably in saturation mode; so next you attempt a solution under the assumption the transistor is operating in saturation mode.

For what it's worth, Fig. 1 shows a SPICE simulation for a 2N2222A NPN BJT in common-emitter configuration with its emitter connected directly to ground. The top graph shows \$V_{CB}\$ versus \$V_{CE}\$, the middle graph shows \$\beta\$ versus \$V_{CE}\$, and the bottom graph shows

- **IC(Q1)** is the collector current (the load line) (blue)
- **IB(Q1)** is the base current (swept linearly from 0 mA – 25 mA) (green)
- **W(Q1)** is the power dissipated by the BJT (red)

versus \$V_{CE}\$. Saturation occurs at the left side of these graphs. When the transistor begins to transition from forward-active mode to soft saturation (note the knee in the \$\beta\$ curve), \$V_{C}=V_{CE}\approx0.3\,\text{V}\$, \$V_{CB}\approx-0.4\,\text{V}\$. When the transistor is in hard saturation @ \$\beta_{sat}=10, V_{CE(sat)}\approx0.12\,\text{V}\$, and \$V_{CB(sat)}\approx-0.9\,\text{V}\$. If this simulation is repeated for many different models of small-signal NPN BJTs, on average the results will be similar to these plots.

[image]

*Figure 1.*

Answer (score 0):

The usual methods like those proposed here, all have problems with accuracy. For a couple of simple and reliable methods to find the edge of saturation then read the paper: “Accurate Measurement of Lifetime of Excess Base Stored Charge at High Collector Currents” by Marian Kazimierczuk.

[Accurate Measurement of Lifetime of Excess Base Stored Charge at High Collector Currents](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cFnpL0o5nHWesDeYqWJp772WAlosR-wP/view?usp=sharing)

Recognize that the base current Ib can be defined as the sum of the base current at the edge of saturation Ibs plus the excess base current Ibx. The current gain BS in saturation region is BS = Ic(sat)/Ib. For an inverter circuit, BS = Ic(sat)/Ibf evaluated at storage time ts > 0. If Kf is the saturation overdrive factor: Kf = Ibf/Ibs then the transistor is saturated if ts > 0, then Ibf>Ibs, Ibx > 0 and Kf > 1. So the transistor is at the edge of saturation if ts -> 0; then Ibf -> Ibs, Ibx->0 and Kf-> 1. See the paper for details and measurement/evaluation methods.